# Dark matter clumping

Tags: cosmology, dark-matter

How can dark matter particles (WIMP's) get ever more densely clumped during the evolution of the universe, as we see for example in the Millennium simulation, if they can't loose kinetic energy by emitting radiation?

Comment: This question has an answer here: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/174977/

Comment: Hi Chris. Kyle has posted a very nice description of this in the question I've linked. Even particles that interact **only** by gravity can clump. Google for [dynamical friction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamical_friction) for more background.